# Package dependencies cannot be resolved when trying to install OpenJDK Java Runtime 8

Tags: java

I'm trying to install OpenJDK Java runtime 8 and whenever I try to it says an error message saying `Package dependencies cannot be resolved` in the details it says

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

openjdk-8-jre: Depends: openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~15.10.1) but 8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~15.10.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
```

How can I get it installed?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the broken dependencies by executing : `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

```
-f, --fix-broken
           Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
           This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
           to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
           specified, these have to completely correct the problem.
```

more details can be found on `man apt-get`